# angular 2 component input binding using expression (map)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component with input of type array

```
class FooComponent  {  
@Input() selectedItemIds:String[];
}
```

and I would like to use map expression in binding in the parent component

```
<app-foo-component [selectedItemIds]='items.map(i=>i.Id)'><app-foo-component>
```

and I get the nice angular error

```
Bindings cannot contain assignments...
```

so what is the solution ?

**Note: I know how to do it in component class.I want to know if it is somehow possible via template
and the code is very brief, I just wanted to show what I was trying to do 
**

Comment: Can you map your items in the `*.ts` file before you try to pass them to the component?

Comment: items are in ts file , it is an array of object

Comment: In other words, you can't do this mapping inside the binding. You need to have prepared the array before trying to pass it. If you're trying to do it this way because your component is being built before your array has finished then put a `*ngIf` on `<app-foo-component...` to force it to run only when your array is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Call the map function in the `*.ts` file before you try to pass it to `<app-foo-component>`. If you're trying to do it this way because your component is being built before your array has finished then create some property hold it.

```
<app-foo-component *ngIf="itemsReady" [selectedItemIds]='items'><app-foo-component>
```

Then in your `*.ts` file you can create some function to do your mapping

```
itemsReady = false;

mapFunction() {
  // do your mapping and when it's complete set this.itemsReady = true
}
```